# How do i make that when i select different item in the listBox it will show me the cropped image for that item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

listbox selected index event:

```
private void listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;
            selectedIndex = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;
            for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rectangles[i] != RectClone)
                {
                    ClearGraphics = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearGraphics = true;
                }
            }
            if (rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex].Width == 0 && rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex].Height == 0)
            {
                Reset.Enabled = false;
                ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
                cm.MenuItems[0].Enabled = false;
                cm.MenuItems[1].Enabled = false;
                cm.MenuItems[2].Enabled = false;
            }
            if (rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex].Width > 5 && rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex].Height > 5)
            {
                Reset.Enabled = true;
                if (IsRectangleConfirmed == true)
                {
                    ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
                    ClearGraphics = true;
                    cropRect = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = true;
                }
                cm.MenuItems[0].Enabled = true;
                cm.MenuItems[1].Enabled = true;
                cm.MenuItems[2].Enabled = true;
            }

        }
```

And the paint event of the pictureBox:

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
        {
            {
                if (ClearGraphics == false)
                {                       
                        if (rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] != Rectangle.Empty)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex]);
                        }                       
                }
                if (cropRect == true)
                {
                    if (recttest.Width > 5 && recttest.Height > 5)
                    {
                        pnt = PointToScreen(pictureBoxSnap.Location);
                        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                        e.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(pnt.X + rect.X, pnt.Y + rect.Y, rect.X, rect.Y, new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height));
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    }
```

The problem is with this part:

```
pnt = PointToScreen(pictureBoxSnap.Location);
e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
e.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(pnt.X + rect.X, pnt.Y + rect.Y, rect.X, rect.Y, new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height));
```

This part draw the cropped rectangle but then when i select another item in the listBox and then back to this item with the cropped rectangle again it's drawing it again and i want it just to remember it and show it again according to the selected item.

This part:

```
if (IsRectangleConfirmed == true)
                {
                    ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
                    ClearGraphics = true;
                    cropRect = true;
                }
```

The IF: if (IsRectangleConfirmed == true) means that i clicked a button and a cropped rectangle created for this item im in now. 
The problem is that when i get back each time to this item the cropped rectangle is drawing over again and i want it to just be shown like it will remember the cropped rectangle for this selected item(index).

What i want to do is a few things:

1. When i draw rectangle on the pictureBox and move between items in the listBox it will remember those items with already drawed rectangle. This part is working.
2. When i click on the button ConfirmRectangle_Click it will make a cropped rectangle from the rectangle i drawed i want that when i move between items in the listBox it will remember those items with cropped image.
3. This line get minimized windows screenshots:

   this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());

I add them to the listBox and when moving between items i see the screenshots of each one in the pictureBox.
I want to do now on items that have cropped image take screenshot of the part of the cropped image only.
If there is no cropped image take screenshot regular from the whole image.

1. This method GetAllWindows show in the listBox the text of the window but what i want to show in the listBox as item is only the name of it.

This is my project in zip file the name is CaptureZip

[CaptureZip](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1012&authkey=!AJgtyn_VhURr0Q0&ithint=file%2Czip)

And this is my project in winrar name Capture:

[Capture](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1013&authkey=!AOLvUKQEyMNiyBY&ithint=file%2Crar)

Comment: You are trying to do something simple but i cannot understand. You choose a list item and an image is shown to picturebox, right? You press a button and you crop the image? When do you draw the rectangle? Where? and how many of them?

Comment: valter my form1 code is a bit long so i added it to here: http://pastebin.com/TNCWXN8d and i draw the rectangle on mouse down and i have a button click ConfirmRectangle_Click when i click it it's making the cropped rectangle. now what i want to do is that when i move between items it will remember the item with the cropped rectangle. Today now it will remember if i drawed a rectangle on the image but not cropped rectangle.

Comment: valter i just updated my question described 4 points of what i need to get that the program will do and also added links to my skydrive of my whole project in zip and rar. If you could take a look at it to see what i mean.

Comment: Nice little program but many bugs when i run it. The rectangle drawing with mouse move tooooo slow. Two questions 1. Draw a rectangle in item 2 without pressing the button. When you select a different item and return to item 2 you want the rectangle to be there? 2. Draw a rectangle in item 2 and pressing the button. When you select a different item and return to item 2 you want to see the rectangle with cropped image?

Comment: valter it should be as it is now in general: if i draw on any of the items a rectangle it will stay on this item if i back to this item later. If i move to item without rectangle if i dont draw on this item rectangle too don't show anything only the image as it is. Same rules for cropped rectangle. If i drawed rectangle and clicked and made it cropped leave this cropped rectangle only on this item. If i move to other items with or without rectangles they shouldnt change.

Comment: The same action should be for all items. In each item you need to draw rectangle with pressing down the mouse button and drag it to set the rectangle size. When you leave the button (mouse up) the rectangle is set/saved only to this item. Other items without rectangles should stay without rectangles if i move to them. Only items i drawed rectangle or cropped rectangle on them should save/remember this drawings. Other items not connected to others. Each item is individual.

Comment: As I imagined. It is not difficult at all but your code is way too complicated. I'll see what i can do to make it run.

Comment: Strange on my pc when i draw rectangle with the mouse it's moving smooth and fast. I wonder if there is a way to check this problem you described on your side.

Comment: valter thank you. Yes my code is is a bit mess. In general it's working like i wanted only the cropped part is not working yet. I guess i could make it much easier and cleaner.

Comment: I dont have a graphic card. If you want to see a delay maximize your form and make the picturebox as big as possible. Trust me. I have done these things many years ago. I always use directx or raw GDI. The past few years i use pure C for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `pictureBoxSnap SizeMode` to `normal`.

```
private bool[] isCropped;
private Image img;
private Image imgClone;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        img = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSnap.Width, pictureBoxSnap.Height);
        imgClone = new Bitmap(pictureBoxSnap.Width, pictureBoxSnap.Height);
        Graphics g;
        using (g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
        }

        pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;
        ...
        ...
        rectangles = new Rectangle[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        isCropped = new bool[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        ...
    }

private void listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        drawpicbox(this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex);
    }

private void drawpicbox(int index)
    {
        Graphics g, g1;
        Size sz;
        WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;
        Bitmap testBmp;

        using (g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            sz = calculateSizeAndPosition(snap.Image.Size);

            if (isCropped[index] == true)
            {
                ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;

                using (testBmp = new Bitmap (img.Width , img.Height )){
                    using (g1 = Graphics.FromImage(testBmp))
                    {
                        g1.Clear(Color.White);
                        g1.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
                    }
                    g.DrawImage(testBmp, rectangles[index], rectangles[index], GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[index]);
                }
            }
            else if (rectangles[index].Width != 0)
            {
                ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = true;
                g.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[index]);
            }
            else
            {
                ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
                g.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
            }

        }

        pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
    }

private Size calculateSizeAndPosition(Size snapSize)
    {
        int wdth, hgt;
        Single  flt;

        wdth = snapSize.Width;
        hgt = snapSize.Height;

        flt = (Single)wdth / (Single)hgt;

        if (wdth <= pictureBoxSnap.Width && hgt <= pictureBoxSnap.Height)
        {

            //return new Size(wdth, hgt);
        }
        else{
            if(wdth >= hgt){
                while (true)
                {
                    wdth--;
                    hgt = (int)(wdth / flt);

                    if (wdth <= pictureBoxSnap.Width && hgt <= pictureBoxSnap.Height)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
            else{
                while (true)
                {
                    hgt--;
                    wdth = (int)((Single)hgt * flt);

                    if (wdth <= pictureBoxSnap.Width && hgt <= pictureBoxSnap.Height)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return new Size(wdth, hgt);
    }

private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (isCropped[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] == false && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Location != RectStartPoint)
        {
            DrawRectangle(e.Location);
        }
    }

private void DrawRectangle(Point pnt)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);


        //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, 50, 50, 300, 200);

        g.DrawImage(imgClone, 0, 0);

        if (pnt.X == RectStartPoint.X || pnt.Y == RectStartPoint.Y)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, RectStartPoint.X, RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.X, pnt.Y);
        }
        else if (pnt.X > RectStartPoint.X && pnt.Y > RectStartPoint.Y) //Right-Down
        {
            rect.X = RectStartPoint.X; rect.Y = RectStartPoint.Y; rect.Width = pnt.X - RectStartPoint.X; rect.Height = pnt.Y - RectStartPoint.Y;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
        }
        else if (pnt.X > RectStartPoint.X && pnt.Y < RectStartPoint.Y) //Right-Up
        {
            rect.X = RectStartPoint.X; rect.Y = pnt.Y; rect.Width = pnt.X - RectStartPoint.X; rect.Height = RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
        }
        else if (pnt.X < RectStartPoint.X && pnt.Y > RectStartPoint.Y) //Left-Down
        {
            rect.X = pnt.X; rect.Y = RectStartPoint.Y; rect.Width = RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X; rect.Height = pnt.Y - RectStartPoint.Y;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
        }
        else //Left-Up
        {
            rect.X = pnt.X; rect.Y = pnt.Y; rect.Width = RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X; rect.Height = RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y;
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rect);
        }

        g.Dispose();

        pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
    }

private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g;
        Size sz;

        if (isCropped[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] == false && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;

            RectStartPoint = e.Location;

            sz = calculateSizeAndPosition(snap.Image.Size);

            using (g = Graphics.FromImage(imgClone))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.DrawImage(snap.Image, (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Width - sz.Width) / 2.0), (int)((pictureBoxSnap.Height - sz.Height) / 2.0), sz.Width, sz.Height);
            }
        }
    }

private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isCropped[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] == false && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Location.X != RectStartPoint.X && e.Location.Y != RectStartPoint.Y)
        {
            ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = true;
            rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] = rect;
            //drawpicbox(this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }

private void ConfirmRectangle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isCropped[this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] = true;
        drawpicbox(this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex);
    }

private void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isCropped[this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] = false;
        rectangles[this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

        drawpicbox(this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex);
    }

private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    { 
        //Nothing
    }

private void RefreshWindowsList()
    {
        Graphics g;            
        g = GraphicsfromImage(img);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        ClearGraphics = true;
        this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
        buttonSnap.Enabled = false;
        this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
        buttonSnap.Enabled = true;
        for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            if (tt.Contains(" ,"))
            {
                listBoxSnap.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        rectangles = new Rectangle[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        isCropped = new bool[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
        textBoxIndex.Text = listBoxSnap.Items.Count.ToString();
        if (this.listBoxSnap.Items.Count > 0)
            this.listBoxSnap.SetSelected(0, true);
        listBoxSnap.Select();
        pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
    }
```

EDIT

Some minor corrections:

```
private void RefreshWindowsList()
    {
        //Graphics g; <- You dont need this         
        //g = GraphicsfromImage(img); <- You dont need this
        //g.Clear(Color.White); <- You dont need this
        //ClearGraphics = true; <- You dont need this
        this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
        buttonSnap.Enabled = false;
        this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray());
        buttonSnap.Enabled = true;
        for (int i = listBoxSnap.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string tt = listBoxSnap.Items[i].ToString();
            if (tt.Contains(" ,"))
            {
                listBoxSnap.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        rectangles = new Rectangle[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        isCropped = new bool[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
        //ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false; <- You dont need this
        textBoxIndex.Text = listBoxSnap.Items.Count.ToString();
        if (this.listBoxSnap.Items.Count > 0)
            this.listBoxSnap.SetSelected(0, true);
        listBoxSnap.Select();
        //pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate(); <- You dont need this
    }
```

Replace `private void DrawRectangle(Point pnt)` with:

```
private void DrawRectangle(Point pnt)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

        g.DrawImage(imgClone, 0, 0);

        if (pnt.X == RectStartPoint.X || pnt.Y == RectStartPoint.Y)
        {
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Firebrick, RectStartPoint.X, RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.X, pnt.Y);
        }
        else
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, pnt.X), Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, pnt.Y), 
                            Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - pnt.X), Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - pnt.Y));
        }

        g.Dispose();

        pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
}
```

Replace `private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` with:

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isCropped[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] == false && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(e.Location.X - RectStartPoint.X) < 10 || Math.Abs(e.Location.Y - RectStartPoint.Y) < 10)
            {
                rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
                drawpicbox(listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = true;
                rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] = new Rectangle(Math.Min(RectStartPoint.X, e.X), Math.Min(RectStartPoint.Y, e.Y),
                                Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.X - e.X), Math.Abs(RectStartPoint.Y - e.Y));
            }
        }
    }
```

Some explanation:

Function `calculateSizeAndPosition()` (should probably be `calculateSize()`), calculates the new size of `snap` image in order to fit to picturebox. It calculates it in a way similar to picturebox zoom mode.

`img` is what picturebox always draws after `pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();`. So, if you want to make any changes to picturebox, draw on `img` and then invalidate.

Valter

Answer (score 1):

As per your previous post you are trying to crop the image by Mouse drag. Now, you want to get that cropped image back when you select that item again after selecting another. In this case after cropping the image you are not setting that cropped image back to the `SelectedItem` so when you select that item again it will show cropped image not its original.

```
Image img = CropImage();
((WindowSnap)listBox.SelectedItem).Image = img;
```

or you can create another property in `WindowSnap` class.

ie. `public image CroppedImage {get; set;}`

So, when you select the item it should check that is item cropped or not. if it is then you can display cropped image instead of original.

```
WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;
selectedIndex = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex.ToString();
///Here you can draw image at your desire position as you have done using e.DrawImage 
///in pictureBoxSnap_Paint event instead of assigning pictureBoxSnap.Image property
this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.CroppedImage
```

;